# Google Java Style: Import names v.s. Import statements?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm looking through [Google's Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) guide and in section **3.3.3 Import Ordering and Spacing** it says:

> Within a group there are no blank lines, and the imported names appear in ASCII sort order. (**Note: this is not the same as the import statements being in ASCII sort order; the presence of semicolons warps the result.**)

I don't get the "Note" part, could somebody please give an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a class with a number at the end.

If you sort the import statements

```
import mypackage.MyClass0;
import mypackage.MyClass;
import mypackage.MyClassA;
```

This is because `0` < `;` < `A` in the [ASCII table.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

If you sort just the names.

```
import mypackage.MyClass;
import mypackage.MyClass0;
import mypackage.MyClassA;
```